# symfony apps share login cookie to and from domain/subdomain

Tags: php, session, cookies, symfony1

We created a project with symfony1.2, our main application is running on our main domain, www.example.com, now we have created another app which we are running from subdomain, sd.example.com, we want to share login of these two apps so that user either login from root domain or subdomain he could access both the apps with same login. 
note:
we have same database for both app
we have file based login system

i did this in factories.yml of example.com and in sd.example.com, but it doesnt seems to work

```
      session_name: mysitesession
      session_path: %SF_CACHE_DIR%/sessions
      session_cookie_domain: .example.com
```

anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

Both cookies need to have the **same name** and **same domain** scope. In your case I think you should force the cookie name:

```
  storage:
    class: sfSessionStorage
    param:
      session_name: my_site
      session_cookie_domain:  .example.com
```

Comment: yea i used same session_name in both apps factories.yml but its not working.

Comment: Are you using the same way to store session (the same `class`)?

Comment: using same way to store session, but codebase is different for both the apps.

Comment: also i just pointed the session folder of both the apps to same location, but it still not working :(

Comment: all above information is valid to enable shared login with multiple apps/subdomain, it was my mistake, another developer set the session storage path in main ProjectConfiguration.class, i changed it and it worked. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To share a login of two apps hosted on separate subdomains, you need to change these settings in **"factories.yml"**

- use same session name
- use same session path
- use same cookie domain name with .rootdomain

factories.yml of **example.com**

```
 storage:
    class: sfSessionStorage
    param:
      session_name: my_site
      session_path: %SF_CACHE_DIR%/sessions
      session_cookie_domain:  .example.com
```

factories.yml of **sd.example.com**

```
 storage:
    class: sfSessionStorage
    param:
      session_name: my_site
      session_path: /var/www/vhosts/example.com/subdomain/mysd/session
      session_cookie_domain:  .example.com
```

if its not working check other config files, may be something overriding in any other config/code file.